# How can I match a string and remove the second matching string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How can I match a string and remove the second matching string.
[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. You'll get a better response if you add details and show how you have tried to solve the problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but I'm assuming what you need is one of the below:

```
=LEFT(D3,LEN(A3))
=TRIM(MID(D3,LEN(A3)+2,1000))
```

Change the 3 to match whatever row you want to perform this on and drag down.

Comment: Thank you Peter.